# Building an Ant JAR

Tags: ant, build.xml

Downloaded Ant and set it up successfully, however when I run from command line I see the following:

```
    C:\>ant
    Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
    Build failed
```

http://pastebin.com/pkHiPnHi

I want to build a JAR file and then invoke that file. Do I just need to bring the build.xml file, containing my project, into my new Ant directory?

Comment: you need to have a build.xml on c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how to write a simple build file :

http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

Comment: Ok, I believe I have the concept. It was easier than I thought. (Sort of an Ant newbie) I went to the directory where the build.xml file was and then I was able to run Ant. By the way, thank you for the link as well. I appreciate this Ricardo, thank you.